# How to see in Edit Comments if comment is from User and her Roles

Tags: plugins, comments, users

I need see in "edit comments" if comments is from registered user and get her roles ex: editor etc, how to? Im not see any plugin with this function.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
function myplugin_comment_columns( $columns )
{
    return array_merge( $columns, array(
        'ruolo' => __( 'Ruolo' )                
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', 'myplugin_comment_columns' );

function myplugin_comment_column( $column, $comment_ID )
{
    switch ( $column ) {        
        case 'ruolo':
            if(get_comment($comment_ID)->user_id != "0")
            {
                if(get_comment($comment_ID)->user_id != "1")
                {
                $ruolo = "";
                $user_meta=get_userdata(get_comment($comment_ID)->user_id);               
                $ruolo = "Registrato";
                if(in_array('vip', ( array )$user_meta->roles))
                $ruolo = "VIP";
                if(in_array('donator', ( array )$user_meta->roles))
                $ruolo = "Donatore";               
                }
                else
                {$ruolo = "Admin";}
                echo $ruolo;
            }
            else
            echo "-" ;
        break;      
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_comments_custom_column', 'myplugin_comment_column', 10, 2 );
```